# iOS PDF Generation: How Do I Draw an MkMapView in PDF?

Tags: ios, pdf, uikit, drawing, mapkit

I'm looking for examples on this, and can't find any, anywhere.

It's very simple. I have an MkMapView with a bunch of annotations. I can print it very easily.

That said, I also want to generate a PDF document from it. The content would be different from what is printed, so I'd be drawing it in a customized manner.

However, there seems to be dearth of examples as to how to do this one particular thing. I can draw pretty much everything else in my view, but the MapKit seems to follow different rules.

I'm hoping the answer is simple, but the lack of examples makes me wonder if it is even possible.

Comment: Have you checked the terms of service? I'm not sure the license for the map tiles (which come from Google) allow printing to PDF. See section 10.10 here: https://developers.google.com/maps/iphone/terms

Comment: Thanks. It's possible that is the case. Maybe that is a way to translate Section 10.2: https://developers.google.com/maps/iphone/terms#section_10_2

Comment: Good point, 10.2 could possibly relate as well. Related question here on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647833/google-maps-and-pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the image with the following code:

```
let render = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: self.mapView.bounds.size)
let image = render.image { _ in
  self.mapView.drawHierarchy(in: self.mapView.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
}
```

Then you can put this image into a PDF:

```
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)

    let documentDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    let outputFileURL = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("mapView.pdf")

    print("URL:", outputFileURL) // When running on simulator, use the given path to retrieve the PDF file

    let pdfRenderer = UIGraphicsPDFRenderer(bounds: mapView.bounds)

    do {
        try pdfRenderer.writePDF(to: outputFileURL, withActions: { context in
            context.beginPage()
            imageView.layer.render(in: context.cgContext)
        })
    } catch {
        print("Could not create PDF file: \(error)")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, but this is how I've programmatically snapped screenshot images of views... then I've added those images to PDFs:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.frame.size, NO, 0.0);

[self drawRect:self.frame];

UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

You'd replace `self` with whatever view you're dealing with. Again, I haven't tested this, but the basic idea is you create a new Graphics context, then tell the target view to draw itself, then capture all of the graphics context info into a UIImage.

Comment: Cool. I'll try this (and ask Apple if I'm allowed to PDF the map), when I get a chance (which might not be for a few days).

Comment: This doesn't work for MKMapView. It just draws nothing into the image.