# Converting google map to pdf in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Am using FPDF I want to plot a google map with dynamic markers in a PDF,as the markers are dynamic so i cant use the static map.How can i plot the map.

I tryed to to assign the map into a variable and try too output that into pdf but it is not working

Comment: Have you checked this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647833/google-maps-and-pdf

Answer (score 0):

I think following links will help you
First download the plugin wp to pdf click on this link-> http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-post-to-pdf/
 Now see the documentation how it works
   http://www.techna2.com/blog/documentation/wp-post-to-pdf/